# What fonts should I specify to render Tufte documents using XeLaTex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, tufte

What font specification commands should I have in my Tufte-based document if I'm rendering it using XeLaTex?

My document renders as expected using pdfLaTeX, but when I switch to XeLaTeX, though everything else works fine, the fonts revert to the bland defaults, and look nothing like those in Tufte's books.

I understand I need something like:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{?}
\setromanfont[?]{?}
\setsansfont[?]{?}
\setmonofont[?]{?}
```

So my question boils down (I think) to what those `?`s should be.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to copy Tufte's typefaces or get advice on other candidate typefaces.

Comment: Both (and either). The result I'm starting from is (as stated) the result I get (without the answers below) looks nothing at all like Tufte because of the fonts used.

Comment: OK, so yo do seem to want to follow Tufte in his choice of style. Bembo is the main font in _Visual Display of Quntitative Information_, which is the only of his books I have (they're expensive:) What kind of document are you working on?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Mostly short idea papers, for which I find Tufte excellently suited. (I'm a beginner too, so partly I'm also interested in kicking the tires and figuring out how things work.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tufte used a slightly modified version of [Bembo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bembo) for the headings and body text. You can purchase Bembo online from [Monotype Agfa](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=215077) (search that site for Bembo to find other packages and individual fonts).  There's a knock-off version that provides the entire family of fonts [cheaply](http://www.fontsite.com/35/bergamo-pro/) and a few of the fonts for [free](http://www.fontsite.com/2077/bergamo-std/).

Tufte used [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) in some of his tables, illustrations, and other places. I believe that Gill Sans comes free with Mac OS X.  If I remember correctly, the Gill Sans design is no longer covered by copyright (though typeface designs in the US are never covered by copyright), so you may be able to find new renderings of it more easily now. (Note that TrueType and OpenType font files themselves may be covered by copyright even if the font design isn't.)

In the Tufte-LaTeX document classes, I've set the monospaced font to use [Bitstream Vera Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera).  This font is freely available from [GNOME](http://www-old.gnome.org/fonts/).  You might also be interested in a derivation of Bitstream Vera called [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) which has an extended character set and is still being actively improved and developed.

Having said all that, by using XeLaTeX, all of the fonts installed on your computer are available for you to use and you're welcome to select any that you like.

As for the font features, here is the setup that I've used for XeLaTeX with these fonts. You're welcome to customize it to your liking.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Bembo}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
```

The `Scale=MatchLowercase` option scales the typeface so that the height of the `x` in each font is the same.

Comment: Are Bembo and Gill Sans fonts available as LaTeX fonts for use with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Not that I'm aware of. There was an older version of the Bergamo fonts that could be converted for use with pdfLaTeX (and the Chantilly fonts from the same site could serve as a replacement for Gill Sans), but I haven't tried those scripts in eons (certainly not since the fonts were updated from TrueType to OpenType).

Answer (score 6):

You should have `sample-book.pdf` on your system in the `tufte` documentation tree (`.../doc/latex/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf`). On page 19 it says

> Tufte’s books primarily use two typefaces: Bembo and Gill Sans. 
>   Bembo is used for the headings and body text, while Gill Sans is 
>   used for the title page and opening epigraphs in Beautiful Evidence.
>
> Since neither Bembo nor Gill Sans are available in default LaTeX installations, the Tufte-LaTeX document classes default to using Palatino 
>   and Helvetica, respectively. In addition, the Bera Mono typeface is 
>   used for `monospaced` type.

Thus I would say

```
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
```

Unless you have Bembo and Gill Sans, of course. I don't know if there is an OpenType version of Bera Mono.

Comment: Pagella has no fi ligature

Comment: Why should it? The "f" doesn't bump into the "i"

Comment: @egreg fi ligatures are nice:-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I believe that Zapf designed Palatino in order *not* to have ligatures.

Comment: @egreg If you don't need ligatures you don't. Personally, I _love_ an _f_ with a large hook that's overlooking the following letter. Perhaps that's why I never liked Palatino. Looking at a sample of _[Palatino](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/palatino/)_, strengthens my belief: the _f_ looks as if it's not allowed to say anything interesting. It's too narrow. Finally (I'd normally have started a paragraph here but the system doesn't let me), with _f_s with large hooks you're bound to need ligatures, which is perhaps why I like them:-).