# What is the default font in the Tufte handout class?

Tags: fonts, tufte

I'm wondering what the default font in the `tufte-handout` class is, and how I could use this font in a different document class (specifically `amsart`.)

Comment: Welcome! Looking at the code: it depends on the class options, if any, the engine used and, obviously, on any additional packages or custom configuration done in the preamble or document. In particular, there is no one default: it is engine-dependent and further depends on the existence or otherwise of certain files.

Comment: If you have a PDF of the document you mean, just inspect the font list in your PDF viewer or using `pdffonts`.

Comment: Iirc, Tufte (the person) likes Bembo.....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you compile a `tufte-handout` document with pdfLaTeX and the default settings, then it uses Palatino and Helvetica for the fonts. You can load these in another document class by adding the following to your preamble:

```
% Palatino for main text and math
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

% Helvetica for sans serif
% (scaled to match size of Palatino)
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}

% Bera Mono for monospaced
% (scaled to match size of Palatino)
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
```

If you're using LuaLaTeX, it substitutes similar fonts:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic, Numbers=OldStyle, Scale = 1.0]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Renderer=Basic, Scale=0.90]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Renderer=Basic]{TeX Gyre Cursor}
```

If you're using XeLaTeX or the `nofonts` `\documentclass` option, then it doesn't load any fonts and will use the defaults for that engine. See the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43623/what-fonts-should-i-specify-to-render-tufte-documents-using-xelatex) for suggestions.

Note that these fonts aren't actually those used in Tufte's books. For more information on that, take a look at page 19 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf).

Also worth noting is that ET Bembo (now called ET Book to avoid potential trademark issues) is [now freely available](https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book).

Comment: ET Book is a `webfont,` so it's not great for LaTeX.

Comment: In this context, note that the [free typesetting font _Cardo_](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/cardo) is [considered to be a close variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bembo#Free_and_open-source_fonts) of _Bembo_ and _ET Book._